# Does the "input" keyword do anything in a SystemVerilog function declaration?

Tags: system-verilog

Is there a difference between these two SystemVerilog function declarations? Does the "input" keyword change any functionality? I've seen it both ways in examples.

```
function int addition (input int a, b);
  return a + b;
endfunction

function int addition (int a, b);
  return a + b;
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between the two functions.  In your code, the `input` keyword is optional.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 13.4 *Functions*:

> Function declarations default to the formal direction **input** if no
> direction has been specified. Once a direction is given, subsequent
> formals default to the same direction.